# If $A$ is an associative algebra Show that $End_{A}(A)=A^{op}$ the algebra with opposite multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be an associative algebra, And let $V$ be a representation of $A$. By $End_{S}(V)$ one denotes the algebra of homomorphisms of representations $V \to V$

Show that $End_{A}(A)=A^{op}$ the algebra with opposite multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: fix $a\in A$ and denote by $R_a:x\mapsto xa$ the right multiplication by $a$. Then $End_A(A)=\{ R_a \mid a \in A\}$. Show that this is isomorphic to $A^{op}$.

Comment: Why don't you use left multiplication ? I think that by Schur's lemma , if $f$ is a homomorphism between two representations $A \to A$ then $f=aId$ where $a$ is in $A$ right ?

Comment: For Schur's lemma you need irreducible representations.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this is an irreducible representation.I forgot about ideals.