# $A$ is an associative algebra and $V$ is a representation. Then $\operatorname{End}_{A}(A)=A^{op}?$ (exercise from notes by Etingof)

Tags: representation-of-algebras

Let $A$ be an associative algebra. If $V$ is a representation of $A$, write $\operatorname{End}_A(V)$ to denotes the algebra of all homomorphisms of representations $V \to V$ . Show that $\operatorname{End}_A(A) = A^{op}$,the algebra A with opposite multiplication.
[If $A$ is an associative algebra Show that $End_{A}(A)=A^{op}$ the algebra with opposite multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315820/if-a-is-an-associative-algebra-show-that-end-aa-aop-the-algebra-with)

In this link,there is an answer: fix $a∈A$
and denote by $R_a:x↦xa$
the right multiplication by $a$
. Then $\operatorname{End}_A(A)=\{R_a∣a∈A\}$. Show that this is isomorphic to $A^{op}$. 
But I think $R$ is not a representation because $R_a R_b=R_{ba} ≠ R_{ab}$. So who is right?

Answer (score 0):

$A^{op}$ has the same underlying set as $A$,with multplication given by:
$$
a\times_{op}b:=ba
$$
Now the map $;$
\begin{align}
\psi:&A^{op}\to End(A) \\
\psi(a)&= R_{a}
\end{align}
satisfies : $$
\psi(a\times_{op}b)=\psi(ba)=R_{a}R_{b}
$$
i.e $\psi$ gives an algebra isomorphism between $A^{op}$ and  $End(A)$.Another equivalent approach is to consider the "evaluation" map:
\begin{align}
ev:&End(A) \to A^{op} \\
ev(T)&=T(1)
\end{align}

Comment: I agree on your answer. But my confusion is that  such R isn't a representation of A, Because R_{a}·R_{b}≠R_{ab}  ,while a representation should be a homomorphism (that is, R_{a}·R_{b}=R_{ab}).